# Gemfile : Specifying a restricted source inside a group

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capistrano

I am trying to run bundle install in a remote machine which does not have access to the gems.internal.com source.
I am running the command:

```
bundle install --without deployment
```

But I get the error:

> Could not fetch specs from http://gems.internal.com

The `deployment-gem` is a required gem only for Teamcity deployment which runs capistrano commands and it's not needed when running `bundle install` on the remote machine.

Here is my `Gemfile` which is inside a bundle I unpack from a `.gem` file in a production server:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rubocop', '0.39.0'
gem 'rspec', '3.4.0'
gem 'rake', '11.1.2'
gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
gem 'rubyzip', '~>1.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'

group :deployment do
  gem 'deployment-gem','0.4', :source => "http://gems.internal.com"
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`bundle install --without` does not install the gems, but still downloads them to check dependencies

If you absolutely cannot make all sources accessible by remote machine - you may go with `bundle package` and checking all gems into repository